# Dynamics 365 Customer Journey analytics not displaying

Tags: dynamics-crm, data-analysis, dynamics-365-ce

So, a bit of an issue here which I cannot figure out.

In the marketing app, when I go look at the "insights" tab of a certain email address we used send out content to (the email address has been deactivated), it's all blank. It doesn't show any "clicks" or anything like that BUT when I go to the "Links" section to check the content provided in the email, when I hover over the content, the analytics display. So, my question is where is this data and why can we see it when I hover over the "links" tab but not in the "insights" tab itself, how can it be fixed?

We tried contacting Microsoft but nothing yet. If anyone has any idea why it does this please let me know. I am analyst so any information would be great.